# Saving a Notepad++-file on Windows 8.1

Tags: notepad++, windows-8.1

I´m writing files for a website in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B). For previewing I use [WampServer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WampServer) and the files are stored in the `.../wamp/www/-directory`.

Using all this on my netbook with Windows 7 starter I never had problems. Now on my new computer with Windows 8.1 it is not going very smoothly.

The problem: I made a change in a file and wanted to be saved, but I got the announcement that the file was in use by another program. I restarted the computer, nothing. I cleaned the computer using AVG-Tune-Up, nothing. I´m not able to save the changes made.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to execute Notepad++ as an Administrator? Or the real solution would be to stop Wampserver services prior to try to save the changes to that specific file.

Comment: It should not be necessary to stop the server to modify files.

Comment: I have seen situation with Windows 8.1 where stuff that used to work simply stop due to some new security check. Hence why I proposed to stop the services. Note that I'm no Windows guru.